# Redis backup with namespace

Tags: redis

How do I backup/dump all the keys containing a specific namespace string? I found all types of scripts to dump and restore Redis data, but nothing on its particular case.

Anyone willing to share a script to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NO, you CANNOT do that.

Comment: See https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools. You can use the --keys flag to only dump keys with a prefix.